# mtc.nodesplit error / Error in data[, "study"] == study : comparison of these types is not implemented

Tags: r

I am running a network meta-analysis on these data:

```
study<-c("Jones", "Jones", "Prieto", "Prieto", "Scott", "Scott", "Mickle", "Mickle", "Yang", "Yang", "Zhao", "Zhao")
sampleSize<-c(3886, 3876, 218, 214, 2040, 2014, 137, 137, 683, 683, 221, 230)
responders<-c(114, 94, 3, 8, 30, 20, 1, 4, 9, 11, 1, 2)
treatment<-c("dx1", "px1", "rx1", "tx1", "rx1", "ax1", "zx1", "tx1", "gx1", "tx1", "ax1", "px1")
df<-as.data.frame(study, sampleSize, responders, treatment)
```

I run the following code to construct the network:

```
#Load packages#
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)

#Create network model#
nw<-mtc.network(data.ab=df, treatments=unique(df$treatment))

#Node split#
nw.nodesplit <- mtc.nodesplit(nw, 
                           linearModel = "random", 
                           n.adapt = 5000, 
                           n.iter = 100000, 
                           thin = 10)
```

Returns the following error

```
Error in data[, "study"] == study : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
```

As an R novice (weaning myself off Stata as I cannot perform Bayesian meta-analyses there) I am unsure how to troubleshoot this. The package documentation for `mtc.nodesplit` did not help me much. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not reproducible code - you are calling `mtc.nodesplit.comparisons(nw.nodesplit)` before `nw.nodesplit` is defined.  Can you update your example?

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece thanks for the quick response - I dropped the ```comparisons= mtc.nodesplit.comparisons(nw.nodesplit)``` as it was optional according to package docs.

Comment: With your example data, I get a different error, "There are no comparisons to assess for inconsistency."  Do you get the "comparison of these types" error when you run with this data?

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece I also get the error you describe here. The error I get in the original post is when using my full data set.

Comment: Try to compile an example data frame that reproduces your error.  Otherwise it's not clear we're working on the same problem.